# jquery ajax not working?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i have a jquery ajax post that for some reasons doesn't work:

```
<script>
var callback = function(data) {
    if (data['order_id']) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>',
            data: { myid: 123456 },
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Transaction Completed!");
            }
        });
    }}
</script>
<?php if ($_POST['myid']) { echo $_POST['myid']; } ?>
```

the 'callback' functions works fine(i test it),  just that it stops at the `ajax post`
and i cant see my `echo`'s

any ideas on what i am doing wrong?

thanks

edit:
i edited the script a bit at the point where the ajax is posting successfully but i cant get the php to echo anything

Comment: Besides the syntax errors, are you by chance trying to do cross domain ajax calls?

Comment: @Martin Jespersen: He's calling `$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]`, so I don't think that is the issue. @Patrioticcow: Aren't there any errors that you can see in the console?

Comment: no errors at all. if i try to see there `XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown` they tell me nothing

Comment: looks like the `Json is Invalid`

Comment: @Patrioticcow  Get your JSON - data and paste it in [link](http://www.jsonlint.com). Maybe it can help you finding the problem

Comment: @Patrioticcow Are you really sure, that calling the actual page you are on (with given POST-parameters) will return JSON-data? I have the feeling you are calling the wrong php-file (so the call fails), but I don't know what your php-script on this page is doing. If the call is correct, just have a look in your php-file and how the json-data gets built. for testing purposes, you could try to use GET-Parameters instead, so you can call the link that returns JSON directly (or use a http-sniffer), so you can have a look at the returned data.

Comment: you have a point. first the `price : orderinfo` was not json valid and if i take that line out i get success on post but i cant echo the posted data

Comment: @Patrioticcow: Am I getting you wrong or are you trying to echo something with PHP after a _client-side_ AJAX-Call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the AJAX - Call is succeeding now, you can't just echo anything with PHP. The data is sent to the client, but PHP is interpreted at the server. You're not sending an HTTP - Request anymore (which is pretty much the point of an AJAX-Call), so PHP is not going to do anything at this point.

You have to add your new content to the DOM with JavaScript. Try this and see if you get the message shown on your page. I append it to the body, because I don't know how your Markup and your returned data looks like:

```
     $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>',
                data: { myid: 123456 },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("Transaction Completed!");
                    $('body').prepend('<p>Successful AJAX - Call</p>');
                }
            });
```

Then you can take a look at your `data`-variable with `console.log(data)`, access the returned data and modify the DOM via JavaScript.

Comment: i get `Successful AJAX - Call` on my page

Comment: did you try out my code? Just try to add something to the DOM that is contained in the returned data-variable the way I showed you. If it's displayed on the page, then everything should be fine.

Comment: for some reason the `data` returns all my page content, wired. I need to do some king of post or get because i need to insert some values in the database

Answer (score 0):

ok, for a start.

```
writeback("Transaction Completed!";
```

fix it to:

```
writeback("Transaction Completed!");
```

Comment: i fix that, but that wasn't the problem

Answer (score 0):

1. you have a trailing comma after `123456`

   ```
   data: { myid: 123456, },
   ```
2. you're missing a closing `}` to your callback function

Comment: i change those things, the ajas is returning success. but i cant see the php echos